# CentOS doesn't know what the internet is

Tags: linux, networking, centos, virtualbox, virtual-machine

So I've done my share of investigating this problem...

I just recently created a CentOS 6 VM on my LinuxMint box using VirtualBox. I left all the recommended values the same upon creation (8GB HDD, 512MB RAM, blah blah blah...). But it DOESN'T connect to the internet! When I try to ping an external network (google.com) it doesn't recognize the host:

```
ping: unknown host google.com
```

and when I try to ping my internal IP of my host box it says that:

```
connect: Network is unreachable
```

(perhaps it can see my host network, just doesn't know a route to it?)

I've cleared my `iptables`, used every single given network adapter VirtualBox offers, and used both NAT and Bridged Adapter modes. I also reaped Google of all that I could mentally find.

When I `ifconfig` it only shows the `lo` interface (loopback), unless I manually enable the `eth0` interface via the `ifcfg-eth0` file (set `ONBOOT="yes"`) and restart. But when I enable the `eth0` interface, it doesn't show an IP; just the MAC and IPv6 one. I don't think its the host's internet or link to the Guest OS at all... I have a WinXP VM set up and it can access the internet.

Perhaps the answer is more obvious than I think?

Comment: If no arguments are given, ifconfig displays the status of the currently active interfaces. `-a` displays the status of all interfaces, even those that are down.

Comment: If you provide information about how you are accessing internet from the host XP machine, then we might provide the solution easily.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try `dhclient -v eth0` - this forces the interface to get an IP via DHCP and this may not be happening for some reason.

Once you have an IP, try `ping 8.8.8.8` - if this works but `ping www.google.com` doesn't, you have a DNS issue (check your `resolv.conf`).

Comment: I noticed the IP is in a different format than that it would normally be in. Does this introduce any security flaws?

Comment: @nonplus It's not clear what you mean.

Comment: Does it look like this - fe80::20f:1fff:fe15:fa73 ? That's an IP version 6 (IPv6) address.  As far as security issues, you need a separate firewall setup for IPv4 (`iptables`) and IPv6 (`ip6tables`) if you need to or are interested in traffic filtering/manipulation from that system.  If you have an external firewall don't worry about it.

Comment: thanks same probably, and worked here as well.  It seems after reseting the interface (ifup/down) it's not initiating a dhcp request.

Comment: hmmm... I set /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0 to be dhcp, but it's not taking effect on boot.  Manually running the command here works, but how can get it to be set to dhcp on boot?

Comment: Entering dhclient -v etho0 solved my problem. I had just installed virtualbox and CentOS 6.3 and couldn't use yum, ping, etc. Ran the above command and presto, centos can now connect to the internet.