# No network connection in CentOS 6.3 Minimal under VMWare Player

Tags: linux, command-line, networking, centos

I'm trying to replicate in VMWare Player the exact same conditions I have under my Dedicated Server for testing purposes.

Now, the thing is that that when I try to install something, or ping http://google.com, it fails since it has no connection.

what do I do to fix it??

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yW8dF.png)

I'm not much of a sys admin, but i'll get there (This is my first Dedicated Server), I ordered a minimal OS to **learn**.

Comment: ifconfig eth0 up

Comment: @LaurentiuRoescu It would be awesome if you could explain me in more detail how to do it. I tried to edit `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0`, and maybe I'm doing something wrong.

Comment: Could it be that you're simply in a too low run-level? What does `who -r` say?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I solved the issue by forcing the interface to get the IP via DHCP

This made the magic:

> dhclient -v eth0

For more detail, check the accepted answer: [CentOS doesn't know what the internet is](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/25395/centos-doesnt-know-what-the-internet-is)

Answer (score 3):

As root/sudo:

Edit `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0` and add to the bottom:

```
BOOTPROTO="dhcp"
```

also change the line that says ONBOOT to read as so:

```
ONBOOT="yes"
```

Now you should run `ifup eth0` and/or reboot your machine. It should pull a DHCP address every time now.